# What does Divine Intervention do when it resolves in a multiplayer game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens in a mulitplayer game when the last counter from [Divine Intervention](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDivine%20Intervention%5d) is removed and the ability ends the game in a draw? Does it resolve as normal the only real difference being a 4-way tie instead of a 2-way tie? What exactly happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rulings below the game clarify how the card works in multiplayer games:

> In a multiplayer game played with the limited range of influence option, Divine Intervention won’t necessarily end the entire game when its third ability resolves. All players within range of Divine Intervention will leave the game. They’ll neither win nor lose; as far as they’re concerned, the result of the game is a draw. All other players will continue playing.

So it depends on the range of influence (rule 801 in the [Comprehensive Rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules)) and the specific variant's rules for draws; in a Free for All (806), the entire game is drawn; in Emperor (809) too (your team's Emperor is always in your range of influence). In Grand Melee (807) it's only a draw for a few players.